# How to make background image stay the same on zoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

Like when someone zooms in on the webpage, it would stay as the original image (preferably in CSS if it can be done)

Answer (score 1):

I have a background image set on the body and use `background-size: 100%` to get it to fill the screen. This would accomplish what you are trying to do. I'm not sure that there would be a good method on any element besides the body.

Comment: i think he is trying to keep the image at the proportional size to the whole window...but even then I'm not totally sure especially since there is not even a complete sentence... :(

Comment: Agreed. My thinking is that this is probably the best that can be done in css. Anything else would require js.

Answer (score 0):

i would think this needs javascript because you need to figure out how big the viewport is per se...whenever that viewport is changed which cannot be detected by css...which is where the javascript comes in. You should look at the javascript/jquery resize browser event. jQuery implements this very nicely with some examples at http://api.jquery.com/resize/ which you should be able to use quite easily.

The example they give is to add the new width of the body when the window is resized...which is the same trigger when the window is zoomed.

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/5acyN/26/). What I've done is first inserted the width of the new viewport. Then I've also readjusted the width and height of the box to be relative to 1/5 of the viewport.

The magical code is:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#log').append('<div>' + $(this).width() + '</div>');
});
```

and what changes the width is:

```
if (logWidth == width/3) {
    console.log("hooray.");
}
else {
    console.log("resize the log please.");
    logWidth = width/3;
    $('#log').width(logWidth);
}
```

This if else statement can be modified for your background image needs.

This gives me the new width which i can use to set the background image/width/whatever of whatever element I want on any resize event.

Comment: @mMoovs what are you referencing with your link, some accompanying text is always necessary...

Comment: Sorry, I was supposed to add more later because I posted the link in a hurry but forgot it. So, the backstretch.js fills the background with given image and holds it on position when zoomed or resizing window. I believe it would suit @Mdays needs here, though it's not done with CSS as OP would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
background-size: cover;      
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Other functionality on this [link](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/take-advantage-css-background-size-property).